# Null character in encrypted data

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, aes

Is it possible that after cbc encryption, **null** character appears in the resulting multibyte data. If yes, what precaution should I take to avoid it.

Comment: You should not take any precaution to avoid it. You should accept that the output of an encryption is binary data, 0 is a valid binary value, and none of your encrypted data should be treated as anything other than pure binary unless you perform a conversion on your own.

Comment: Repeat after me. String is not a container for binary data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible that after cbc encryption, null character appears in the resulting multibyte data.

Absolutely. It would not be a pseudo-random function if values like 0's were missing.

> If yes, what precaution should I take to avoid it.

Treat everything as a `byte` array with embedded `NULL`s. Never treat it like a `char*`.

If you want to treat it like a `char*`, then you will need to encode it first. Try hexadecimal, Base32 or Base64.